# How to fetch PHP script without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Edit:** I've resolved the redirect issue and the error; however, now the form data is undefined when I submit it. I've updated the code provided to reflect the changes.

I have a PHP script that performs a query and echos some HTML markup. I'm trying to use javascript to fetch the markup and update the DOM without triggering a redirect.

Is this possible?

Also getting a `TypeError` when trying to manipulate the DOM. Fairly new to this so not really sure where I'm going wrong.

For the `TypeError`, I've tried using DOMContentLoaded but that breaks my form input fields. The code provided simplified for brevity.

**PHP Script:**

```php
<?php
    if(!include('../connect.php')){
        die('error retrieving connect.php');
    }

    try {
        $dbh = ConnectDB();

        if(isset($_POST['startDate'], $_POST['endDate'])){
            $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
            $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];

            echo '<table><tr><th>' .$startDate. '</th>' . '<th>' .$endDate. '</th></tr></table>';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        die($e);
    }
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```html
<div id="desktopMetrics" style="display: none">
    <form method="post" action="api/get_desktop_metrics.php" name="desktopMetricsForm" id="desktopMetricsForm">
        <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="start">Start date:</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" > 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="end">End date:</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                 <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col" id="desktopMetricsTable"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const desktopMetricsForm = document.getElementById("desktopMetricsForm");
    desktopMetricsForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formattedFormData = new FormData(desktopMetricsForm);
        desktopMetricsPostData(formattedFormData);
    })
})

async function desktopMetricsPostData() {
    const response = await fetch('api/get_desktop_metrics.php', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: formattedFormData
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    document.getElementById("desktopMetricsTable").innerHTML = data;
}
```

I expect that on submit, the markup will be fetched and inserted into the `innerHTML` of the empty div with `id="desktopMetricsTable"`. Currently, the markup is fetched but is displayed in plain text on a new page.

Comment: Try adding an event listener for `submit` event instead of `click` on your `desktopMetricsForm` form

Comment: the "redirection" is because you submit a form - if you don't want to submit a form, either don't use a form, or handle the form submit event, and use preventDefault to prevent the form from submitting (don't handle click on the submit button)

Answer (score 1):

The function should be executed under 'submit' event instead of 'click'

```
const desktopMetricsForm = document.getElementById("desktopMetricsForm");
  desktopMetricsForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    const formattedFormData = new FormData(form);
    desktopMetricsPostData(formattedFormData);
    return false;
  })

  async function desktopMetricsPostData() {
    const response = await fetch('api/get_desktop_metrics.php', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
      body: formattedFormData
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    document.getElementById("desktopMetricsTable").innerHTML = data;
  }
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense @Eric. I still have the issue of an unresolved TypeError caused by lines 1 & 2 in the javascript portion. Wrapping it in a DOMContentLoaded function fixes the error but makes my date inputs not work.